# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException when called CloseableIterator.next()

Tags: android, ormlite

My code is as follow.

```
QueryBuilder<MyObject, UUID> qBuilder = enctDao.queryBuilder()
                .orderBy(MyObject.COLUMN_NAME_LAST_UPDATED, false);
qBuilder.where()
                .eq(MyObject.COLUMN_NAME_EID, eid)
                .and().eq(MyObject.COLUMN_NAME_STATUS, MyObject.STATUS_NORMAL)
                .and().isNull(MyObject.COLUMN_NAME_PID);

CloseableIterator<MyObject> iterator = enctDao.iterator(qBuilder.prepare());

try {
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        MyObject ecThread = iterator.next();
        if (ecThread.getSticky() == 0) {
            normalResult.add(ecThread);
        } else if (ecThread.getSticky() < 0) {
            stickyResult.add(ecThread);
        }
    }
 } finally {
     iterator.close();
     qBuilder.clear();
     enctDao.clearObjectCache();
 }
```

When I call next() in while loop, it throws
"android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 requested, with a size of 3"

Full error stack trace of ORM Lite is as follow.

```
02-14 17:35:22.808 W/System.err( 4583): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 requested, with a size of 3
02-14 17:35:22.811 W/System.err( 4583): at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
02-14 17:35:22.811 W/System.err( 4583): at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
02-14 17:35:22.811 W/System.err( 4583): at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
02-14 17:35:22.811 W/System.err( 4583): at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseResults.getString(AndroidDatabaseResults.java:134)
02-14 17:35:22.811 W/System.err( 4583): at com.j256.ormlite.field.types.StringType.resultToSqlArg(StringType.java:39)
02-14 17:35:22.811 W/System.err( 4583): at com.j256.ormlite.field.BaseFieldConverter.resultToJava(BaseFieldConverter.java:24)
02-14 17:35:22.811 W/System.err( 4583): at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.resultToJava(FieldType.java:819)
02-14 17:35:22.811 W/System.err( 4583): at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.BaseMappedQuery.mapRow(BaseMappedQuery.java:60)
02-14 17:35:22.811 W/System.err( 4583): at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.getCurrent(SelectIterator.java:270)
02-14 17:35:22.811 W/System.err( 4583): at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.nextThrow(SelectIterator.java:161)
02-14 17:35:22.811 W/System.err( 4583): at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.next(SelectIterator.java:173)
```

I use 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48' for my project.

Comment: is there any other manipulation done with the iterator inside the wile loop?

Comment: check if the iterator is changed in any *other thread* also !!

Comment: @Kaddath I do not have other manipulation on that iterator inside the while loop. Now I added the complete code of my method.

Comment: As @Kaddath asks, is there another thread which is removing items from the same table that is being iterated over?